# Annotation software for multi camera setup

Tags: camera, annotation, tracking, geometry

## Background

I have multiple, synchronized cameras with partial overlapping views. I already have object tracking applied to the objects in the videos I get from these cameras. Now I want to have a tool that shows me these videos, including the tracks, and enables me to say that a certain set of tracks in different videos belong to the same object.

Basically I am searching for a free, accessible and more developed alternative for the following annotation tool:

[image]
Code: https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/multicam-gt

Note that the above tool seems to suit my needs, but I wonder if there is not a more professional tool available.

For my needs the [CVAT](https://github.com/opencv/cvat) annotation tool is almost perfect, except for the fact that only a single view can be annotated at the same time, thus making it hard to annotate in a multi camera setup.

## Must haves

- Support for bounding box annotation of multiple camera views add the same time.
- Free of charge
- Runnable on my own pc, i.e. not in the cloud

## Nice to haves

- Works with camera calibration, i.e. adjusting the location of a bounding box in camera 1 changes the bounding box locations in different camera views once these bounding boxes have been linked.
- Works with masks instead of bounding boxes
- Multi user support
- Deep learning model support
- Python code base
- Runs under Linux